# Using Boost::Xpressive to match a single character

Tags: c++, regex, boost, boost-xpressive

I have a string that can be "/" "+" "." or a descriptive name

I'm trying to figure out how to use regex to check if the string matches any of the 3 special characters above (/ + or .)

After doing a bit of reading i decided boost::xpressive was the way to go but i still cannot figure it out.

is Boost:xpressive suitable for this task and what would my regex string need to be?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use `std::string::find_first_of()` to do your own solution?  Sounds like a lot of machinery for a fairly simple task.

**Edit**

Try this out if you're still stuck.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/xpressive/xpressive.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::xpressive;

int main()
{
   sregex re = sregex::compile("[+./]|[:word:]+");

   sregex op = as_xpr('+') | '.' | '/';
   sregex rex = op | (+alpha);

   if (regex_match(string("word"), re))
      cout << "word" << endl;
   if (regex_match(string("word2"), re))
      cout << "word2" << endl;
   if (regex_match(string("+"), re))
      cout << "+" << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

There are two ways to do the same thing shown.  The variable named `re` is intialized with a perl-like regular expression string. `rex` uses Xpressive native elements.

Comment: I'm trying to learn about regex and i couldn't figure the solution to the question above. I think it was the escaped characters next to each other was confusing me.

Comment: @TomFLuff: Well then, that's different.  Regular expressions are very powerful tools, so keep on digging into them. Just keep in mind not to overly complicate a solution to use something cool (I constantly have to remind myself of this).

Answer (score 1):

I would say that Boost.Xpressive may be overkill for the task, but it's your call.

Regular expression are life savers when you want to validate a particularly formatted string. Here, there is no format involved, only a set of possible values. My advice : if your problem can be solved by simple, successive string *equality* comparisons, than you probably don't need anything like regular expressions.